# Run python script multiple times inside shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to run the below shell script:

```
PATH=`python getvar.py path`
PATH_REPO="$PATH/$FOLDER_NAME/"
echo "path repo is $PATH_REPO"
ESP=`python getvar.py esp`
echo "esp is $ESP"
DPLYR=`python getvar.py deployer`
echo "deployer is $DPLYR"
recipients_list=`python getvar.py recipients`
echo "recipient list is $recipients_list"
REMOTE_USER=`python getvar.py remoteuser`
echo "user is $REMOTE_USER"
```

I am getting the output as:

```
 path repo is /home/developer/user1
./test.sh: line 14: python: command not found
esp is
./test.sh: line 16: python: command not found
deployer is
./test.sh: line 18: python: command not found
recipient list is
./test.sh: line 21: python: command not found
user is
```

The python file is executing for only 1st command. If run it individually via terminal, it is giving me output, but not from shells script.
How do I make same python script run multiple time in shell script?

Comment: in the first line you overwrite your `PATH` variable so subsequent calls can't find python

Comment: @fourjr no it doesn't. The error is due to the fact OP is overriding the `PATH` variable

Comment: There are a bunch of all-caps variable names with special meanings, so it's best to use lower- or mixed-case names to avoid conflict (unless you *do* want one of those special meanings). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization/673940#673940)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is looking in the PATH environment variable for the python interpreter. PATH is a very special environment variable. In step one you are replacing the PATH environment variable with the output of `python getvar.py path`

I would do the following:

1. Do you really want to use the special variable "PATH"?
2. If so, ensure that `python getvar.py path` includes the path to the python interpreter
3. Or save the path to the Python interpreter before you change the PATH variable

I would suggest you change your script as follows:

```
MYPATH=`python getvar.py path`
PATH_REPO="$MYPATH/$FOLDER_NAME/"
echo "path repo is $PATH_REPO"
ESP=`python getvar.py esp`
echo "esp is $ESP"
DPLYR=`python getvar.py deployer`
echo "deployer is $DPLYR"
recipients_list=`python getvar.py recipients`
echo "recipient list is $recipients_list"
REMOTE_USER=`python getvar.py remoteuser`
echo "user is $REMOTE_USER"
```